# How to change global location settings

Tags: time, location

I'm an American currently living in Israel.  The system recognizes that I am in Israel (either automatically via the internet or that's what I told it when I installed Ubuntu) which is fine, because I have the correct time/date, but it also assumes that I want the calendar in Hebrew.  I have the same problem with Google - it always sends me to Google Israel by default and puts everything (including search results) in Hebrew.  That's probably my through my IP, though.  If the computer thought that it's in America, I would be fine manually setting the clock.  Is there a way I can tell the computer that it's in the US or something of the sort to work out these issues?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format and language of your time and date by going to "language support" (type it in the dash) in the tab "regional format".